# android edit text making the text larger

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textattributes

When a user types into my edittext the text is a bit small, Id like to make this larger maybe 20-25 sp what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<EditText 
    android:textColor="#000000"   
    android:background="@drawable/textboxbg"
    android:layout_width="726px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:id="@+id/number" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"
/>
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm a big fan of starting out with system-defined values.  You can always tweak things later.

```
 <TextView style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" ...
```

Probably better in the long run to define yourself a family of styles in res/values, rather than the one-shot that I'm showing here.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [textSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextSize) attribute of the EditText view.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply add a [textSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextSize) attribute to your XML layout? BTW, for unit dimensions `dp` is preferred over `sp`

Comment: sp is preferred for text. On http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html, "A dp is a density-independent pixel that corresponds to the physical size of a pixel at 160 dpi. An sp is the same base unit, but is scaled by the user's preferred text size (it’s a scale-independent pixel), so you should use this measurement unit when defining text size (but never for layout sizes)."